# MySQL auto completion

Tags: mysql, autocomplete

How can I use MySQL tab completion ? The line *auto-rehash* is already in my *my.cnf* file. The completion works with *select* command but it doesn't work with *source* command.

Comment: MySQL completion only works with names in the database, such as table and column names. It doesn't extend to the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only tab-complete SQL identifiers, not filesystem paths.  As documented under [`--auto-rehash`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_auto-rehash) (emphasis added):

> This option is on by default, which enables database, table, and column name completion.

You might prefer to direct your SQL source file to the stdin of the `mysql` command line tool using stream redirection:

```sql
$ mysql -u myuser -p mydb < /path/to/myfile.sql
```